# Can I run job-dsl-core with Jenkins plugins in command line?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I know about job-dsl-core single jar and I have tried to use it, but when my DSL scripts have references to Jenkins plugins like hipchat it fails generating the job configuration xml because it doesnt have loaded the extension point provided by the Jenkins plugin.

I have used the command described here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#run-a-dsl-script-locally

How I can run it with Jenkins plugins loaded in the context?